# Notepad++ How to apend something different to each line

Tags: notepad++, text-editor

Alright I will try to be as specific as possible. I am presented with a very unique issue.

So let's say I have 1,000 lines in notepad++. We will say lines of code. Lets also say each line looks like the following. Will use this as example:

```
<a href="" class="note has_notes" title="(1789-1797)" data-note="">
<a href="" class="note has_notes" title="(1797-1801)" data-note="">
<a href="" class="note has_notes" title="1801-1809)" data-note="">
<a href="" class="note has_notes" title="(1809-1817)" data-note="">
```

I know how to append or prefix data to these lines. (I know how to add code before and after)

These lines are not complete. At the end of each line I need to add 'something'. **However**, each 'something' is different. **But** each 'something' is in order with each line of code.

Example:

```
George Washington</a>
John Adams</a>
Thomas Jefferson</a>
James Madison </a>
```

Lets say I have a list of presidents. From the first to last in order. I have them copied to my clip board in that order so when I paste them they paste in that order as well. Now the first 4 lines of code above (with dates) are in the same order as the presidents. I need to be able to copy paste and each president append to the end of each line in corresponding order.

Comment: I am assuming that you want a solution on windows since you are using npp. Do you have access to a Unix machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can download [GNU utilities for win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/?source=dlp). Then just extract it. It is a collection of ported tools for Windows. Very handy.

Then use the `paste` program from there. You can find it in

```
extracted_folder\usr\local\wbin\paste.exe
```

The you can use it from Windows command prompt.
 To merge two files line by line

```
path_to\paste.exe file1.txt file2.txt > merged.txt
```

to merge three files with a delimiter ';'

```
path_to\paste.exe -d ";" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > merged.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an edit that Notepad can do. It seems a simple merge operation, web searching for "merge two files" should provide lots of possibilities. Most I can think of require some programming skills. What programming languages do you know or can use?

Alternatively, you could paste one file into a column of a spreadsheet and the other file into an adjacent column, then save the spreadsheet to some form of text file.

Comment: I can write a very small bit of PHP and Python. I would think a script would be easy. A simple loop script maybe. Define each line. Move and append line 1 from file 1 to line 1 file 2 so on and so forth. Just don't quite have the understanding of the two languages I think I would need to achieve that goal. =/